# Algorithm for checking positive definite matrix over a subspace

Tags: algorithms, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

There is an algorithm that for any input matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $x^\top A x>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, e.g. by using Cholesky algorithm. Is there an algorithm that, for matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, check if $x^\top A x >0$ for all $x \in V \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Oops you are right, thank you! Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Use Gram-Schmidt to construct an orthonormal basis $\{u_i\}$ of $V$, and use your  algorithm on the matrix with entries $u_i^\top A u_j$.

Comment: Do you mean Cholesky algorithm on matrix with entries $u_i^\top A u_j$?

Comment: Whichever algorithm you want to use for checking positive definiteness.

Comment: Great, I will try it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Is it important for the basis to be orthonormal?